# Can't override jnlp podTemplate & container - Jenkins declarative pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, kubernetes-pod, jnlp, declarative

I'm using jenkins on kubernetes cluster, installed with helm chart as below,

```
helm install my-jenkins jenkinsci/jenkins -n jenkins \
--set controller.serviceType=LoadBalancer \
--set controller.servicePort=8888 \
--set persistence.existingClaim=jenkins-pvc \
--set persistence.accessMode=ReadWriteMany
```

Also tried --set agent.enabled=false but also graps the default jnlp image

And tried to override the jnlp agent by below pipeline, but it skip my definition and pull the default `jenkins/inbound-agent:4.3-4` image.

My pipeline:

```
pipeline {
  
    agent {
        kubernetes {
            cloud 'kubernetes'
            label 'jnlp'
            defaultContainer 'jnlp'
            yaml """
                apiVersion: v1
                kind: Pod
                metadata:
                labels:
                    label: agent
                    jenkins: slave
                name: jnlp
                spec:
                containers:
                - name: jnlp
                  image: nurhun/my_custom_jenkins_inboud_agent:v1.0
                  args: ['\$(JENKINS_SECRET)', '\$(JENKINS_NAME)']
                  env:
                  - name: CONTAINER_ENV_VAR
                    value: jnlp
                  - name: JENKINS_AGENT_WORKDIR
                    value: /home/jenkins/agent
                  - name: JENKINS_URL
                    value: http://my-jenkins.jenkins.svc.cluster.local:8888/
                  - name: "JENKINS_TUNNEL"
                    value: "my-jenkins-agent.jenkins.svc.cluster.local:50000"
                  volumeMounts:
                  - mountPath: "/home/jenkins/agent"
                    name: "workspace-volume"
                    readOnly: false
                  - name: jenkins-docker-cfg
                    mountPath: /var/run/docker.sock
                volumes:
                - name: jenkins-docker-cfg
                  hostPath:
                    path: /var/run/docker.sock
                - emptyDir:
                    medium: ""
                    name: "workspace-volume"
            """
        }
    }

      
    stages {

        stage('Build') {
            agent {
                kubernetes {
                    label 'jnlp'
                    defaultContainer 'jnlp'
                }
            }

            steps {
                sh "docker build . -t custom_image:${IMAGE_TAG}"
            }
        }
     }
}
```

I also tried to set the `Defaults Provider Template Name` as below, but still doesn't work.

[image: Defaults Provider Template Name]

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

I would try specifying the container you want to use like this:

```
stages {
    stage('Build') {
        steps {
            container('jnlp'){
                sh "docker build . -t custom_image:${IMAGE_TAG}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[See more](https://plugins.jenkins.io/kubernetes/)

Comment: didn't work because the initiated pod itself run with the default jnlp, so it didn't matter